# Is there a VBA code ( for Access 2016) to create a blank / any PNG file

Tags: ms-access, png, qr-code

Sadly i've no code to share, but it's an easy question. I'm looking for piece of code that will create some png file ( can be blank, colored, what ever ) with a specific name ( QR_[ID].png ).

In my case it's to store a QR code gotten with `Print DownloadHTTP( URL, DestinationPath )`

The url is : "https://qrickit.com/qrickit_apps/qrickit_api.php" which will generate the qr code

DownloadHTTP will just access that url with the specific ID and download the image to then change the existing file in DestinationPath to the QR code image downloaded

The code works on a already created PNG, so the creation of a png file is the only missing part. But i can't find a way to create some png file and google is not being friendly with me today :(.

Worst part is i'm not an administrator on windows so can't do almost anything.

Thanks if people try to help !

Comment: Just use a default .png file, and copy it before overwriting the copy.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you have the [GDI+ flat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat), you can use that to draw and save to PNG. It's nontrivial, but doable to use GDI+ code in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert, resize, flip, rotate, merge and even create Images use the [WIA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-startpage)-Libary

Some Examples can be found at [devhut.net](https://www.devhut.net/2019/06/04/vba-wia-flip-an-image/)

```vb
Public Sub CreateBlankPngImage()

Dim PathToCreatedImage As String
PathToCreatedImage = "" ' insert path and filename here

Dim sFormatID As String
sFormatID = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}" 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-consts-formatid

Dim sExt As String
sExt = "PNG"

Dim oWIA As Object    'WIA.ImageFile    
Set oWIA = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")

Dim v As Object ' Wia.Vector
Set v = CreateObject("WIA.Vector")

v.Add &HFFFFFFFF 'White (A=255,R=255,G=255,B=255)

Set oWIA = v.ImageFile(1, 1) ' create image with size 1x1

With CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
    .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Scale").FilterID
    .Filters(1).Properties("MaximumWidth") = 200 'Width
    .Filters(1).Properties("MaximumHeight") = 200 'Height

    .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
    .Filters(2).Properties("FormatID") = sFormatID 'convert to PNG
    .Filters(2).Properties("Quality") = 100

    Set oWIA = .Apply(oWIA) 'process image
End With

oWIA.SaveFile PathToCreatedImage

Set v = Nothing
Set oWIA = Nothing
End Sub
```

Of course for your purpose, copying a default PNG-File would be sufficent-

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine for creating a white image, but it doesn't work correctly for any other color. Here's the result using `&HFF2D7D9A&` (Cool blue):

[image]

There appears to be a bug in the WIA Scale filter. I did extensive testing and found that the issue occurs regardless of image type (bmp, png, jpg). The look will vary, but it won't be a solid color (check the bottom right corner of the image). It doesn't matter if the source is a vector, as in the case of this code, or a file created with an external program, such as MSPaint. It also doesn't matter if it's a VBA or VBS script and I would expect the same result using any other language.

To workaround the bug, I had to make the start image bigger (I settled on 20x20 as a reliable size after a lot of trial and error testing), pad the target image larger than the desired size by at least 6% of the longest dimension (I picked 10% to be safe), and finally crop the extra padded pixels before saving in the desired format.

Obvious question: Why not just create the vector to the desired size, instead of using the Scale filter? Answer: It takes too long to do it that way (for a full screen size image) because you have to do an `.Add` for each pixel.

Here's the code with workarounds added:

```
Public Sub CreateBlankPngImage()

PathToCreatedImage = "" ' insert path and filename here

wiaFormatPNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
ARGB = &HFF2D7D9A& 'Cool blue
ImageWidth = 1920
ImageHeight = 1080
Pad = Int(0.1 * ImageWidth)

Set oWIA = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
Set v = CreateObject("WIA.Vector")

For i = 1 To 400
    v.Add ARGB
Next

Set oWIA = v.ImageFile(20, 20)

With CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
    .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Scale").FilterID
    .Filters(1).Properties("MaximumWidth") = ImageWidth + Pad
    .Filters(1).Properties("MaximumHeight") = ImageHeight + Pad
    .Filters(1).Properties("PreserveAspectRatio") = KeepAspect
    .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Crop").FilterID
    .Filters(2).Properties("Right") = Pad
    .Filters(2).Properties("Bottom") = Pad
    .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
    .Filters(3).Properties("FormatID") = wiaFormatPNG
    Set oWIA = .Apply(oWIA)
End With

oWIA.SaveFile PathToCreatedImage

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a cool solution using Microsoft Office Power Point Object Model. The basic algorithm for creating a blank PNG image file is this:

1. Instantiate the `PowerPoint.Application` object.
2. Create a presentation with an invisible window.
3. Create a blank slide in the presentation.
4. Create a rectangle shape in the slide.
5. Remove the outline of the rectangle shape.
6. Set the fill color of the shape to white or any desired color.
7. Export the shape in PNG format.
8. Do the clean up.

That's it! Take a look at the code and read the comments in the code to find out how to change the dimensions of the created image, change its background color, .etc.

```
Sub CreateBlankPngImage()
    Dim pngPath As String
    pngPath = "" ' insert path and filename here
    Dim width As Single
    Dim height As Single
    ' The dimensions of the PNG image
    width = 200
    height = 200
    ' The background color of the PNG image is defined below.
    ' The color is in the format bbggrr, where bb, gg and rr
    ' are hexadecimal numbers ranging from 1 to 255 and
    ' specify the components of the color.
    Dim bgColor As String
    bgColor = "ffffff"

    Dim oPP, oPresentation, oSlide, oShape
    
    Set oPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set oPresentation = oPP.Presentations.Add(0)
    
    Const ppLayoutBlank = 12
    Set oSlide = oPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
    
    Const msoShapeRectangle = 1
    Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, width, height)
    
    oShape.Line.Visible = 0
    
    ' Uncomment the following line if you want your PNG
    ' to be completely transparent!
    'oShape.Fill.Visible = 0
    
    oShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = CLng("&h" & bgColor)
    
    Const ppShapeFormatPNG = 2
    oShape.Export pngPath, ppShapeFormatPNG
    
    oPP.Quit
    Set oPP = Nothing
    Set oPresentation = Nothing
    Set oSlide = Nothing
    Set oShape = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can also pass other constants instead of `ppShapeFormatPNG` to the `Export` method in order to store the blank image in other formats. If you do so, be sure to change the file name extension in the first parameter as well. These constants are listed below along with their numeric values:

- `ppShapeFormatBMP = 3` to export the image as bitmap (*.bmp*)
- `ppShapeFormatEMF = 5` to export the image as Enhanced Windows Metafile (*.emf*)
- `ppShapeFormatGIF = 0` to export the image as Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif*)
- `ppShapeFormatJPG = 1` to export the image as *.jpg*
- `ppShapeFormatPNG = 2` to export the image as Portable Network Graphics (*.png*)
- `ppShapeFormatWMF = 4` to export the image as Windows Metafile (*.wmf*)

As a side note, I'm just wondering why the TIFF (Tag Image File) format is missing among these constants! Rather strangely, Microsoft Power Point is **definitely able** to export a shape in TIFF format since it has this option in the "Save As type" list when you right-click on a shape and select "Save as picture..."!