# The WIA.Vector object loses the transparency of its pixels after invoking its ImageFile property

Tags: vbscript, transparency, wia

The title of this question can also be, "**The alpha values in the `WIA.Vector` object don't work.**"
I'm trying to render an ellipse on a transparent background using my own discovered algorithm, and then save the resulting image into a *.bmp* file. The ellipse is rasterized properly with a black stroke, but my program does not make the background of the image transparent.
As I examined the program, it turned out that when I retrieve an `ImageFile` object from the `Vector` object, its `IsAlphaPixelFormat` property is set to false, indicating that the alpha channel is not available in the output image. Even though I set the alpha value of the background color to zero in the vector, the `ImageFile` object generates an opaque white background.

So could you please help me make the background transparent? Here is my VBScript code, which must be run with `cscript.exe`.
**Note:** This program requires Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) library v2.0 in order to create a *.bmp* image file. So it must be run on **Window Vista** or higher.

```
Const width = 500
Const height = 500
color_transparent = GetARGB(0, 255, 255, 255) ' This does not work, renders as opaque white
color_black = GetARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)
PI = 4 * Atn(1)

Dim oVector, oImageFile

Set oVector = NewBlankPage()
rasterizeEllipse oVector, 220, 120, 200, 100, color_black

Set oImageFile = oVector.ImageFile(width, height)
oImageFile.SaveFile "ellipse.bmp"

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Done! Press Enter to quit."
WScript.StdIn.SkipLine

Function NewBlankPage()
    Dim oVector, i
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Creating a new blank page... Please wait..."
    Set oVector = CreateObject("WIA.Vector")
    
    For i = 1 To (width * height)
        oVector.Add color_transparent
    Next
    
    Set NewBlankPage = oVector
End Function

Function getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, d)
    Dim theta
    theta = d * Sqr(2 / (rx * rx + ry * ry))
    ' theta = 2 * PI * d / getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry)
    
    Dim point(1)
    point(0) = Fix(cx + Cos(theta) * rx)
    point(1) = Fix(cy - Sin(theta) * ry)
    getPointOnEllipse = point
End Function

Function getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry)
    getEllipsePerimeter = Fix(PI * Sqr(2 * (rx * rx + ry * ry)))
End Function

Sub SetPixel(oVector, x, y, color)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    
    If x > width Or x < 1 Or y > height Or y < 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    oVector(x + (y - 1) * width) = color
End Sub

Sub rasterizeEllipse(oVector, cx, cy, rx, ry, color)
    Dim perimeter, i
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Rendering ellipse..."
    perimeter = getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry)
    
    For i = 0 To (perimeter - 1)
        Dim point
        point = getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, i)
        SetPixel oVector, point(0), point(1), color
    Next
End Sub

' These functions are taken from examples in the documentation
Function Get1ByteHex(val)
    Dim s
    s = Hex(val)
    Do While Len(s) < 2
        s = "0" & s
    Loop
    Get1ByteHex = Right(s, 2)
End Function

Function GetARGB(a, r, g, b)
    Dim s
    s = "&h" & Get1ByteHex(a) & Get1ByteHex(r) & Get1ByteHex(g) & Get1ByteHex(b)
    GetARGB = CLng(s)
End Function
```

After running the code, you can test the transparency of the output image using this simple HTA:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="blue">
<img src="ellipse.bmp">
</body>
</html>
```

And you will see that a white box is displayed behind the ellipse, which indicates non-transparent background.

Comment: Relevant: [rgba not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6515551)

Comment: I recently dealt with an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71655781/15764378) that may be related. I'll take a look at this tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the `ARGB` filter to change all white pixels to transparent and saving the image as a PNG file. Unfortunately, this means iterating through every pixel, so your script will take twice as long to run. I could not find a way to create the initial image with transparency. See [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?889525-WIA-2-0-Vector-Add()-method-slow) for info regarding the performance issue. Here's the revised script:

```
Const wiaFormatPNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
Const width = 500
Const height = 500
color_white = GetARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
color_transparent = GetARGB(0, 255, 255, 255)
color_black = GetARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)
PI = 4 * Atn(1)

Dim oVector, oImageFile

Set oVector = NewBlankPage()
rasterizeEllipse oVector, 220, 120, 200, 100, color_black
Set oImageFile = oVector.ImageFile(width, height)
Set IP = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
IP.Filters.Add IP.FilterInfos("ARGB").FilterID
Set oVector = oImageFile.ARGBData
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Changing white pixels to transparent... Please wait..."
For i = 1 To oVector.Count
    If oVector.Item(i) = color_white Then oVector.Item(i) = color_transparent
Next
IP.Filters(1).Properties("ARGBData").Value = oVector
IP.Filters.Add IP.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
IP.Filters(2).Properties("FormatID").Value = wiaFormatPNG
Set oImageFile = IP.Apply(oImageFile)
oImageFile.SaveFile "ellipse.png"

Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Done! Press Enter to quit."
Wscript.StdIn.SkipLine

Function NewBlankPage()
    Dim oVector, i
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Creating a new blank page... Please wait..."
    Set oVector = CreateObject("WIA.Vector")
    
    For i = 1 To (width * height)
        oVector.Add color_white
    Next
    
    Set NewBlankPage = oVector
End Function

Function getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, d)
    Dim theta
    theta = d * Sqr(2 / (rx * rx + ry * ry))
    ' theta = 2 * PI * d / getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry)
    
    Dim point(1)
    point(0) = Fix(cx + Cos(theta) * rx)
    point(1) = Fix(cy - Sin(theta) * ry)
    getPointOnEllipse = point
End Function

Function getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry)
    getEllipsePerimeter = Fix(PI * Sqr(2 * (rx * rx + ry * ry)))
End Function

Sub SetPixel(oVector, x, y, color)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    
    If x > width Or x < 1 Or y > height Or y < 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    oVector(x + (y - 1) * width) = color
End Sub

Sub rasterizeEllipse(oVector, cx, cy, rx, ry, color)
    Dim perimeter, i
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Rendering ellipse..."
    perimeter = getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry)
    
    For i = 0 To (perimeter - 1)
        Dim point
        point = getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, i)
        SetPixel oVector, point(0), point(1), color
    Next
End Sub

' These functions are taken from examples in the documentation
Function Get1ByteHex(val)
    Dim s
    s = Hex(val)
    Do While Len(s) < 2
        s = "0" & s
    Loop
    Get1ByteHex = Right(s, 2)
End Function

Function GetARGB(a, r, g, b)
    Dim s
    s = "&h" & Get1ByteHex(a) & Get1ByteHex(r) & Get1ByteHex(g) & Get1ByteHex(b)
    GetARGB = CLng(s)
End Function
```

Note: If you only need an ellipse in your HTA, it can be done instantly with CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<style>
.ellipseDiv
{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  border: 1px solid #005;
  border-radius:200px / 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="blue">
<div class=ellipseDiv>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! As a side note, I'm not going to display an ellipse in an HTA with CSS (I already know how to do it with VML as well). The code that I provided in this post was just a simple example to illustrate my problem. Rather the actual complex app that I'm working on is an [Image Mixer](https://github.com/javadbayat/Threading/blob/main/multithreading%20example.hta) where the problem is that the transparent portions of the two input images get opaque in the output composite images. It's better not to discuss it here, though your answer helps me fix that problem, too.

Comment: I expected it was something like that, but wanted to cover all bases. Glad my answer, on the WIA transparency issue, helped.